# How to say ${foo}123 in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm building a shell script that is checks the existence of log files in a loop. The log files I'm trying to open are named like this: `access_log-%02d00-%02d59` with %02d being an hour. In perl I could just say `"access_log-${hour}00-${hour}59"`. But how do I do that in shell script? Here's my code. It doesn't work because it thinks the var name would be `$HOUR00` and `$HOUR59`.

```
for HOUR in 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23; do
   if [ -e tmp/access_log-$HOUR00-$HOUR59 ]; then
        # do stuff here
   fi
done
```

Comment: I'm pretty dumb. Of course `${HOUR}00` works in shell script too. I just had a typo in it. -.-

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks for the edit. Typo :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I works just the same as in perl. `${HOUR}00` does the trick.

Comment: please remember to accept your answer, too. Then it will stop showing as unanswered.

Comment: I know, but I have to wait for two days. ;-)

Comment: In Shell programming you would be well-advised to get in the habit of always writing, for example,`${HOUR}` in lieu of simply `$HOUR`.